# flutter web not downloading image ,the image is displaying but on clicking download it gives Error: XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

On flutter web,images are displaying but on clicking download it is showing following error,Pls provide a solution for production environment ,editing flutter files allow images to download only on test environment.

`Error: XMLHttpRequest error. dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 299:10  createErrorWithStack dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 355:28            _throw dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 120:5                                           throwWithStackTrace dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1385:11                                          callback dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15 <fn>`

i had used **image_downloader_web: ^2.0.2**

```
if (kIsWeb)
await WebImageDownloader.downloadImageFromWeb(
        "$image_url",
        imageQuality: 100,
        name: 'image',);
}
```

The image url is a public url,not hosted on my server.
On android the image gets downloaded easily using following code:

```
    var response = await Dio().get(
            "$image",
            options: Options(responseType:ResponseType.bytes));
    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
                                  Uint8List.fromList(response.data),
                                  quality: 100,
                                  name:"image");
```

Answer (score 0):

The XMLHttpRequest error usually occurs when there is a CORS issue with the server hosting the image. Check if the server has allowed cross-origin requests from your domain. You can try adding the following headers to the server response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
```

Comment: As i had mentioned that image is hosted on another server, i only have a url of that image,
so what can i do in dart code for downloading on web .